# Pytest not skipping tests when mixing parametrize and skipif

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.5

I have this testing code:

```
import pytest


def params():
    dont_skip = pytest.mark.skipif(False, reason="don't skip")
    return [dont_skip("foo"), dont_skip("bar")]


@pytest.mark.skipif(True, reason="always skip")
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param", params())
@pytest.mark.skipif(True, reason="really always skip please")
def test_foo(param):
    assert False
```

Yet `test_foo` is not skipped, even though there are `skipif` decorators attached to `test_foo` (I tried in both orders, as you can see above):

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.5.0, pytest-2.8.5, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /Volumes/Home/Users/Waleed/tmp/python/explainerr/test, inifile: 
collected 2 items

test/test_example.py FF

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
________________________________ test_foo[foo] _________________________________

param = 'foo'

    @pytest.mark.skipif(True, reason="always skip")
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("param", params())
    @pytest.mark.skipif(True, reason="really always skip")
    def test_foo(param):
>       assert False
E       assert False

test/test_example.py:13: AssertionError
________________________________ test_foo[bar] _________________________________

param = 'bar'

    @pytest.mark.skipif(True, reason="always skip")
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("param", params())
    @pytest.mark.skipif(True, reason="really always skip")
    def test_foo(param):
>       assert False
E       assert False

test/test_example.py:13: AssertionError
=========================== 2 failed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

If I change this line

```
dont_skip = pytest.mark.skipif(False, reason="don't skip")
```

to

```
dont_skip = pytest.mark.skipif(True, reason="don't skip")
```

then it skips the test cases:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.5.0, pytest-2.8.5, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /Volumes/Home/Users/Waleed/tmp/python/explainerr/test, inifile: 
collected 2 items

test/test_example.py ss

========================== 2 skipped in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

How do I get `pytest.mark.skipif` to work when also using skippable parameters with `pytest.mark.parametrize`? I'm using Python 3.5.0 with Pytest 2.8.5.

Comment: This could be a bug... ?

Comment: Does your real code have more complicated skipif expressions, or are they literally just True and False?

Comment: @pfctdayelise My real code has more complicated expressions which resolve to booleans, and it also doesn't work. I've raised a bug report: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1296

Answer (score 0):

The pytest version that you are using is very old. I used your code in my env and two tests are skipped at first skipif marks.

```
python3 -m pytest test_b.py
==================================================================================== test session starts =====================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.9.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir:<redacted>, inifile:
collected 2 items

test_b.py ss                                                                                                                                                                           [100%]

====================================================================================== warnings summary ======================================================================================
test_b.py:9: RemovedInPytest4Warning: Applying marks directly to parameters is deprecated, please use pytest.param(..., marks=...) instead.
For more details, see: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html
  @pytest.mark.skipif(True, reason="always skip")
test_b.py:9: RemovedInPytest4Warning: Applying marks directly to parameters is deprecated, please use pytest.param(..., marks=...) instead.
For more details, see: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html
  @pytest.mark.skipif(True, reason="always skip")

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
=========================================================================== 2 skipped, 2 warnings in 0.03 seconds ============================================================================
```